# Required Java version of Maven Dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I developed and built my Java application using Maven. I need to support Java 1.6, so I use the following properties:

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
```

Still, when I run the application I get an "Unsupported major.minor version" error and I suspect that one of my dependency jars is compiled with a Java version newer than the one I need to support.

**My questions:**

1. Is this even possible? I thought Maven would take care of this kind of dependency version problems.
2. Is there an easy way to find out the minor/major version of all my dependencies? (Would be awesome if it could be shown when doing `mvn dependency:tree` for instance.)

Comment: Can you post your entire maven file?

Comment: Have some stuff I'd rather not disclose on SO in there such as certificate information. But here's a stripped down version of the relevant parts: http://pastebin.com/BE7yDbSV

Comment: It looks like Jersey 2.6 was the last version compiled in java 6. After that it was java 7.
Reference: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html

Comment: Ok. I think jackson is a problem as well. I too could probably dig this information up manually. This answers neither of my two questions though.

Comment: I found where jackson 2.3 is compiled in java 6. I can't find anything definitive on 2.4. As for your questions, 1) maven won't make that kind automatic downgrade, you have to specify it your self. 2) I'm not aware of a good way to find out the major/minor version dependencies. That doesn't mean one doesn't exist though.

Comment: Can u include maven compiler plugin explicitly and compile code again?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that every dependency (maintainer) can decide on its own which java version is used to compile (1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 etc) so this is not solvable via Maven. But you can make sure that you don't use dependencies which are using a different Java version than you like to have.

This can be enfored by using [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) by using [extra-enforcer-rules](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html):

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version> <!-- find the latest version at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/ -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                  <maxJdkVersion>1.6</maxJdkVersion>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org.mindrot:jbcrypt</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </enforceBytecodeVersion>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-5</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

This will break your build if you have a dependency which is compiled with a different version of JDK than you want to have.

Comment: That's neat. I assume these rules are applied to transitive dependencies as well?

Comment: Excerpt from the docs: `This rule checks the dependencies transitively and fails if any class of any dependency is having its bytecode version higher than the one specified.` See http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html

Comment: Took me some googling to get here. Much appreciated.

Comment: can be invoked with `mvn validate`

Comment: Is there a particular reason for excluding jbcrypt ?

Comment: Just to show that you can exclude particular dependencies which otherwise would break the build.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your two questions:

Yes, this is possible. Looking at the [`docs`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), the `<maven.compiler.target>` and `<maven.compiler.source>` properties simply tells Maven which version of `javac` to use to compile **your** project. And I quote, for your reference:

> Note: Merely setting the *target* option does not guarantee that your
>   code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is
>   unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs which would
>   make your code fail at runtime with a linkage error. To avoid this
>   issue, you can either configure the compiler's boot classpath to match
>   the target JRE or use the Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin to verify your
>   code doesn't use unintended APIs.

The [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) after the `Unsupported major.minor version` error actually tells the version of the JRE the class file is compatible with:

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

I don't know if there is an easy way to tell the major/minor version of ALL the dependencies (and transitive dependencies) in a project though.

UPDATE: Though I haven't used it before, I wonder the [Animal Sniffer Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) will help to sniff out the major/minor version of your dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately the animal sniffer is only for your own written code and not for dependencies. Based on the thing that a dependency in Maven is a binary artifact which has been compiled with whatever version you can't set the version of compiler in your build to force the versions of dependencies.