# Maven dependency is dependent on which Java version?

Tags: java, maven-3

Could you please suggest how to check maven dependency is dependent on which Java version?

For example - would like to understand Google Gson 2.8.1 is dependent on which java version.

Please suggest the best approach the validate the same. One approach could be to go through release document but then there are lots of release documents like README.md, ReleaseProcess.md, UserGuide.md etc. which becomes confusing at times.

There exists libraries dependent on Java 9. So is there any other angle to it apart from saying that this library uses Java 9 features internally.

Also, is there any internet link where list of libraries along with their Java version could be found.

Comment: read its documentation

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get this information just using Maven dependencies. I think it would need to be checked on a case-by-case basis. But I'd be happy to be wrong.

Comment: The only way I can imagine would be if you could manage to use a variable in the dependency definition that contains the Java version. But hen you would have to provide an own version of your library for each Java version.

Comment: Read about **maven enforce plugin**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559830/required-java-version-of-maven-dependency