# How to get maven to use the installed java to create the jar file?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to create a jar file from my spring project. I use the command `mvn package`. These are the contents of my pom.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cgny</groupId>
    <artifactId>apm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apm</name>
    <description>APM</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- latest influxdb dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- XMl Parser -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

The source and target has been set to java 1.8, but when I run the jar file using `java -jar`, I get the `UnsupportedClassVersion` error.

I know this happens because the version of java which compiled the project is different from the one I am using to run the jar file, but my java version is 1.8.0_51, which I have also tried as the target and source in the pom file, with the same result.

JAVA_HOME and the PATH variable have been set with the correct directories.

How do I configure maven so that it just uses the installed java?

Edit: The error message-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/cgny/apm/ApmApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Required Java version of Maven Dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559830/required-java-version-of-maven-dependency)

Comment: >The source and target has been set to java 1.8, but when I run the jar file using java -jar, I get the UnsupportedClassVersion error.< [We need to see that](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors). The libraries also need to be <= 1.8 compiled

Comment: Run "mvn -version" and make sure that maven uses the same Java version that is defined in your JAVA_HOME

Comment: The maven java version is the same as the JAVA_HOME version.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `com/cgny/apm/ApmApplication` was compiled with Java 16 and therefore cannot be used with Java 8.

Comment: But I am running it with Java 16 when i get this error.

Comment: You set source and target to 1.8.

Comment: They have been set to 1.8

Comment: Yes, so how do you expect it to work if you set source and target to Java 8, but you want to use a component with bytecode for Java 16?

Answer (score 0):

The compiled jar was fine, I just had java 8 installed, which was somehow overriding the JAVA_HOME and Path variables. The java -version now shows 16 instead of 1.8.